# Eloqua campaign integration with Salesforce CRM ID

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

Integrate Eloqua Campaign object to Salesforce Campaign object.

we need to create replicate campaigns in two Salesforce instances from Eloqua. As we have two company running in one eloqua

IS this possible to create two unique identifier in eloqua, or go with other solution